# Disable Twilio Scaler to send SMS

Tags: twilio

I have a several Twilio phone numbers to send SMS messages to users (2-way sms).

And I want to try Copilot and Messaging service features, but I have my own logic around how I chose the number to send SMS from. 
So I need to be able to choose a "from" number by myself.

If I will provide "from" number and MessagingServiceSid at the same time, will this disable Messaging Service Scaler logic?

*Sorry, but I can't just test it on my account right now. But I see Twilio Java SDK want me to provide "from" number OR "MessagingServiceSid" but not both.* Many thanks.

Comment: If you are picking numbers yourself, what benefit do you get from the messaging service?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't set both a `MessagingServiceSid` and a `From` number when sending a message. You can either let the messaging service decide which number to use to send your messages (using it's Geomatching, fallback and scaling features) or you need to send the messages using the `From` number of your choice using the regular API.